# Can "ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection" be a problem in aws lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can this anyhow in the feature damage the flow they belong to?

I have a lambda that works behind a API Gateway websocket endpoint.

This simply asks for a clientId and a message payload, query all connections on dynamo for that clientId (multi device realtime dashboard frontend) and updates all interested users.

It's working fine if you test trought "wscat" on command line but it is buggy on real world browser using js websocket api or c# websocket api.

Doest this exceptin has anything to do with it?

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

require("aws-sdk/clients/apigatewaymanagementapi");

const ORDERS_TABLE = "ordersTable";

const successfullResponse = {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: "everything is alright"
};

module.exports.sendMessageHandler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event);
  sendMessageToAllConnectedClientDevices(event)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("sucesso", data);
      callback(null, successfullResponse);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("erro: ", err);
      callback(null, JSON.stringify(err));
    });
};

const sendMessageToAllConnectedClientDevices = async event => {
  try {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const { clientId } = body;
    console.log(
      "handler.sendMessageToAllConnectedClientDevices.clientId: ",
      clientId
    );

    const connectionIds = await getConnectionIds(clientId);

    return await Promise.all(
      connectionIds.Items.map(connectionId => {
        send(event, connectionId.connectionId);
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("erro sendMessageToAllConnectedClientDevices");
    return error;
  }
};

const getConnectionIds = async clientId => {
  console.log("handler.getConnectionIds.clientId: ", clientId);

  const params = {
    TableName: ORDERS_TABLE,
    // IndexName: "client_gsi",
    FilterExpression: "clientId = :cliend_id",
    // KeyConditionExpression: "clientId = :cliend_id",
    ProjectionExpression: "connectionId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":cliend_id": clientId
    }
  };

  console.log("handler.getConnectionIds.params: ", JSON.stringify(params));

  const data = await dynamo.scan(params).promise();
  return data;
};

const send = async (event, connectionId) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const postData = body.data;

  const endpoint =
    event.requestContext.domainName + "/" + event.requestContext.stage;
  const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
    endpoint: endpoint
  });

  const params = {
    ConnectionId: connectionId,
    Data: postData
  };

  return await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise();
};
```

ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with API Gateway, check how you are handling information passing through to Lambda function (because browser sends some extra information as compared to command line call)